# `assert` in loop

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, assert

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    assert(x[i] > 0);
```

When not debugging (`NDEBUG` flag), the resultant is an empty `for` loop. Is there a clean way to handle this (not executing the empty `for` loop); preferably without preprocessor directive, since it would defeat the purpose of `assert` in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by "handle this"?

Comment: get rid of the loop that does nothing

Comment: The compiler will probably do that anyway.

Comment: if you refactor the loop into a function of it's own and than assert on the return value...

Comment: @Luchian The compiler does not know that `x.size()` has no side effects.

Comment: @Oswald: that depends. If it's defined in a header (like `std::vector::size`), then the compiler can infer it.

Comment: @Oswald Not even when it's dealing with a standard container?

Comment: I don't know if the compiler is allowed to assume, that what is in the `std` namespace actually adheres to the C++ Standard Library specification.

Comment: @Oswald if `size()` has side-effects, why would you want the loop optimized out?

Comment: @Luchian This is not the point. The point is, if the compiler can determine whether `size()` has side effects. Because the compiler is only allowed to optimize away the loop, if it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good optimizer should be able to eliminate the entire loop when `NDEBUG` is defined (I've just tested mine, and it does do that).

Alternatively, you could surround the entire loop with `#ifndef NDEBUG` / `#endif`. You say this "would defeat the purpose of `assert` in the first place", but I don't really follow the reasoning.

Comment: if I use preprocessor directives than I might as well wrap around what I like to assert and throw an `exception`, `exit` with error or something (Dont use assertion at all).
assertion eliminates the need for this dirty code. Or I could be wrong!

Answer (score 7):

```
inline bool all_positive(std::vector<int> const &x)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
        if (x[i] <= 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

then

```
assert(all_positive(x));
```

(although this may get you an "unused function" warning when `NDEBUG` is defined).

Comment: Well, the OP can always wrap the function definition in a pre-processor conditional :).

Answer (score 4):

`assert` statements become no-ops if `NDEBUG` is defined. To do something similar for the whole loop, you could do

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    assert(x[i] > 0);
#endif
```